# Couchbase - Failed to access the view

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-view, nosql

I have a bucket with more than 9M record. And I have 10 views on this bucket. I am getting documents from view by paging with couchbase-client:1.4.2 . I have already defined this view on that bucket so it should be ready for query. After querying more than 100 times i am getting **RuntimeException : failed to access the view ...**

For the first query my stale is **FALSE** and then i am trying to query with **OK**.

this is my sample query **?limit=5000&skip=530000&stale=ok** .

Is there anybody have any idea ?

Comment: Have you made sure to publish your views to production setting?  Couchbase defaults to production mode so will look there for the views and not in the development section.

Comment: Off course i publish it, i got this exception after 100 paging query. If i havent publish it, i would got exception on first querying

Comment: Sorry didn't read that part, provide more info such as machine specs, the mapping code, size of what you are outputting and the code you are using to access the view.  Also provide the full exception.